# Arabic text appears letter by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to capture div which contains arabic letters and English letters and image when I press preview button every thing is okay but Arabic text appears letter by letter how to solve this?[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUgT5.png) you can see how it's working
[Here is a link](https://sudan-ads.com/u.html)

Comment: Please provide more context/details to the question as well code so that we an understand and try to help.

Comment: I believe this is a problem with your browser. The Arabic text looks connected correctly for me. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your page head contain encodage utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```